# Magento 1.8 Multi-Store in folder - 404 error

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore

I'm trying to create a multi store site for a Magento 1.8 CE installation.
I followed this tutorial: https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-configure-multiple-magento-storefronts.html

Basically I created the folder for the new store, copied index.php and .htaccess, created the symlinks, and modified in index.php with the corresponding parameters for Mage::run.

is there anything I missed?

Comment: you can fallow this link may be it is useful for you   http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-set-up-and-manage-multiple-stores.html#gref

Comment: Sorry I followed the instructions but I still get 404

Comment: for this way we don't need symlinks just folders and .htccess index file